# Top stack by rep profile problem

Tags: bug, profile-page

PLDI doesn't appear on my list of top SE sites by reputation on my profile page. I see this on other people's accounts too. Why is this happening? Is it because we are a beta site? But Community Building is listed, and it is in beta too...

Comment: You can see a list [on the area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127456/programming-language-design-and-implementation) but it's a bit slow to update

Comment: This may be because we're in private beta.

Comment: [This page also shows users sorted by reputation](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=newusers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site is still in *private* beta, which means it has limited visibility. Your account will appear on your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts) (without badges, but that's [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359110/295232)) but not (yet) on your site-specific profiles. In a few weeks, the situation will no doubt be different ...

Answer (score 1):

The site is in **Private Beta**. The **Private** implies that the site will be hidden from users who do not have a direct link or invitation. This includes hiding the site from the accounts list on user profiles from non Private Beta sites.